# Spring STS project explorer Spring Elements Beans

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have just discovered that in the Spring STS if you go the Project Explorer and look under spring elements there is a bean section which shows a view of all xml beans and also annotation beans.

I've noticed that it picks up the beans from the *servletname*-servlet.xml file (both xml and annotation beans) but it is not picking up beans from the root application context which is located in /recources/META-INF/spring/ and is named spring-application.context.xml.

I guess this is because it does not know where to look. Is there a way to tell it to look there?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on your project and select 'Properties' from the menu.
Then go to the page 'Spring >> Bean Support >> Config Files'.

See screenshot:
[image]